# Jquery show hide multiple divs with Toggle & change price with ParseFloat (improve newbie code)

Tags: jquery, css

This is my first attempt at JQuery and I've probably gone about this with way too much code.

I have 2 links that Toggle hide multiple divs and also alter the pricing above...

Essentially I think I've probably done this in an extremely inefficient and naive way - any help on how to make my code better would be great.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.partner-info').hide();
    $('.children-info').hide();
    $('#partner-cross').hide();
    $('#children-cross').hide();

        $('.add-partner').click(function(){
        if ( $('.partner-info').css('display') == 'block' ) {
        $('.partner-info').toggle();
        $('#partner-cross').toggle();
        $('#add-partner').text("add partner");
        $('#partner-li').toggleClass('selected');
        $('#Lvl01').html(parseFloat(parseFloat($('#Lvl01').html())-10.00).toFixed(2));
        $('#Lvl02').html(parseFloat(parseFloat($('#Lvl02').html())-18.00).toFixed(2));

        } else {
        $('.partner-info').toggle();
        $('#partner-cross').toggle();
        $('#add-partner').text("for your partner");
        $('#partner-li').toggleClass('selected');
        $('#Lvl01').html(parseFloat(parseFloat($('#Lvl01').html())+10.00).toFixed(2));
        $('#Lvl02').html(parseFloat(parseFloat($('#Lvl02').html())+18.00).toFixed(2));
        }
        });

        $('.add-children').click(function(){
        if ( $('.children-info').css('display') == 'block' )    {
        $('.children-info').toggle();
        $('#children-cross').toggle();
        $('#add-children').text("add children");
        $('#children-li').toggleClass('selected');
        $('#Lvl01').html(parseFloat(parseFloat($('#Lvl01').html())-0.50).toFixed(2));
        $('#Lvl02').html(parseFloat(parseFloat($('#Lvl02').html())-0.50).toFixed(2));

        } else {                                          
        $('.children-info').toggle();
        $('#children-cross').toggle();
        $('#add-children').text("for your children");
        $('#children-li').toggleClass('selected');
        $('#Lvl01').html(parseFloat(parseFloat($('#Lvl01').html())+0.50).toFixed(2));
        $('#Lvl02').html(parseFloat(parseFloat($('#Lvl02').html())+0.50).toFixed(2));
        }
        }); 

});


     <table class="edutable">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="first"><strong>Plan level</strong></td>
                    <td class="second"></td>
                    <td class="third">1</td>
                    <td class="fourth">2</td>
                </tr>                    
                <tr>
                    <td class="first"><strong>Monthly price</strong></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td class="monthly-prices"><strong>&pound;<span id="Lvl01">10.00</span></strong></td>
                    <td class="monthly-prices"><strong>&pound;<span id="Lvl02">18.00</span></strong></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="first"><br /></td>
                    <td><br /></td>
                    <td><br /></td>
                    <td><br /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" class="tabs">
                        <div class="tabsinner">
                            <div class="benefits">Benefits:</div>
                            <ul>
                             <li class="selected"><span>for you</span></li>
                             <li id="partner-li"><span><a href="#" id="add-partner" class="add-partner">add partner</a></span></li>
                             <li id="partner-cross"><a href="#" id="cross-p" class="add-partner"><img src="images/cross.gif" /></a></li>
                             <li id="children-li"><span><a href="#" id="add-children" class="add-children">add children</a></span></li>                                                                                                     <li id="children-cross"><a href="#" id="cross-c" class="add-children"><img src="images/cross.gif" /></a></li>
                            </ul>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="4" class="heading">Essential Cover <span>(1 year benefit period)</span></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                <td class="first"><strong>Dental</strong></td>
                <td class="second">
                 <div class="you">Just for you</div>
                 <div class="partner-info">Partner</div>
                 <div class="children-info">Dependent Children</div></td>
                <td>
                 <div class="you"><span class="small">up to </span><strong>&pound;65</strong></div>
                 <div class="partner-info"><span class="small">up to </span><strong>&pound;65</strong></div>
                 <div class="children-info"><span class="small">up to </span><strong>&pound;65</strong></div></td>
                <td>
                 <div class="you"><span class="small">up to </span><strong>&pound;120</strong></div>
                 <div class="partner-info"><span class="small">up to </span><strong>&pound;120</strong></div>
                 <div class="children-info"><span class="small">up to </span><strong>&pound;120</strong></div></td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

To see the HTML & CSS here is a link to jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/superhanzzz/mVByn/

Thanks

Westy

Comment: Boy, that is a lot of DOM queries.

Comment: I'm new to this so would appreciate any guidance

Answer (score 1):

Well there are a lot of things that could be optimized imho.

A short list on the javascript:

- Remove the first 4 call to `hide()`, it's better to just add the following css `#children-cross,.partner-info,.children-info,#partner-cross{display:none;}` in your css declaration.
- Both click options ave a lot of thing in common, you could factorize them
- Inside each click the inside of the if and the else have also a lot in common, and could be grouped as well.

If you don't want to search how to do that by yourself, here is an example of some JavaScript that will do the same (there may be some stuff to improve/change in there but it's just to get an idea) :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.add-partner').click(function(){
       handleClick("partner",10,18);
   });
   $('.add-children').click(function(){
       handleClick("children",0.5,0.5);
   });       
});

function add(a,b){
   return a+b;
}

function minus(a,b){
   return a-b;
}

function handleClick(keyword,plan1Diff, plan2Diff){
   var condition = $('.'+keyword+'-info').css('display') === 'block';
   var newText = (condition) ? "add "+keyword:"for your "+keyword;
   var func =(condition) ? minus : add;
   $('.'+keyword+'-info').toggle();
   $('#'+keyword+'-cross').toggle();
   $('#add-'+keyword).text(newText);
   $('#'+keyword+'-li').toggleClass('selected');
   $('#Lvl01').text(func(parseFloat($('#Lvl01').text()),plan1Diff).toFixed(2));
   $('#Lvl02').text(func(parseFloat($('#Lvl02').text()),plan2Diff).toFixed(2));
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Py - I'll study this and see if I can understand your methods

Comment: If you have any question about them, just ask, i'll try to answer :)